# Algorithm to minimize capital gains tax

Tags: capital-gains-tax, software, cryptocurrency, free, open-source

I've made thousands of cryptocurrency trades and have them in a CSV file with the necessary fair market values.

I'd like to use the specific-shares cost basis method to minimize my gains.

Is there a minimization algorithm that I could use to do this programmatically?

Or, is there any free open source software that could do this for me?

I found some interesting articles:

- [TokenTax: 2017 Was the Perfect Storm for Crypto-Tax-Minimization Accounting](https://medium.com/tokentax/2017-was-the-perfect-storm-for-crypto-tax-minimization-accounting-b1a6489109e0)
- [Betterment: Lower Taxes with Our Improved Cost Basis Accounting Method](https://www.betterment.com/resources/lowering-your-tax-bill-by-improving-our-cost-basis-accounting-methods/)

But, neither company seems to have published their algorithms. They also both require you to sign up, pay, and upload your trading data.

Comment: In the U.S., you can designate your sales but it must be done at the time of the sale.  You can't pair them off at your whim as your linked article suggests. I don't know a thing about crypto or the rules for their taxation but I would assume that it's no different.  Check with a tax professional rather than some guy on the web trying to sell you a Token Tax minimization algorithm.  The Betterment article indicates this: "WHEN  Betterment customers sell securities, our algorithms select which specific lots to sell."  they key word is WHEN.

Comment: Cryptocurrency trades are not subject to wash sale accounting. So I can recommend the 'KBH Investor Accounting' software. However, the software requires manual input but will then output a continuation sheet that can be adapted to tax reporting. The CSV file could be converted, by an application developer, to a KBH input file.

Comment: I suppose that cryptocurrency trades are subject to short-term versus long-term capital gains. So yeah, designated trades need some type of system of designation. If the trades were put on a 4797 then they would just be income and marked-to-market at year-end if not closed out.

Comment: You could always keep trading and then all your gains will vanish.  No need to pay me for that advice.

Comment: @BobBaerker [IRS Notice 2014-21](https://www.irs.gov/irb/2014-16_IRB#NOT-2014-21) says that crypto "is treated as property". Where does the IRS say that you can't change the method you used to determine the cost basis of an asset after you've sold it? Feel free to answer this question: [Can I change a cost basis method retroactively?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/116062/can-i-change-a-cost-basis-method-retroactively)

Comment: @SSpring thank you for that recommendation. Where can I find the 'KBH Investor Accounting' software? I googled it but didn't find it. What do you mean by "Cryptocurrency trades are not subject to wash sale accounting"? Does that mean I'm allowed to change the cost basis method I used? Feel free to answer this question: [Can I change a cost basis method retroactively?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/116062/can-i-change-a-cost-basis-method-retroactively) I reported the sales on Form 8949. Should I have put them on Form 4797? I filed as an individual who is single.

Comment: @PeteB. I thought of that, but I don't think individuals are allowed to carry back a net capital loss.

Comment: Well, cryptocurrency trades are not subject wash sale accounting. The problem is that a software not designed for professional traders would be applying wash sale accounting. And yeah, the IRS expects cryptocurrency trades on a Form 8949 unless the trader is making hundreds of trades per day and claiming trader-status. The advantage of using a Form 4797 is just that all loses can be set against overall income. If there is no net capital loss then that is even better.

Comment: @SSpring OK. Well, if the software is open source, I could potentially modify it. OK. Thank you.

Comment: The software I mentioned doesn't do wash-sale accounting and became popular with trader-status traders. So it should be good for cryptocurrency trades. Just separate long-term trades from short-term trades in the output. Use the 'Sup App v8' for output similar to an 8949. The software will run a transaction file of its own design so what is needed is a file conversion from CSV.